# mysql query - select not finding a value

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

Can someone please help me rework this query, so that I can obtain the outer_config.contractorsRef value. Currently it is not finding the value. I have highlighed it below in the code. I have purposley written the query with count(*) and the select in a sub query as it performs alot faster than count(distinct).

```
SELECT outer_config.contractorsRef AS cref, outer_config.contractorsRef AS contractorsRef, noworkers
FROM bis.request_config AS outer_config
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT request_config.contractorsRef, (
        SELECT COUNT( * ) subcount
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT subcontractorRef
            FROM bis.Request
            INNER JOIN bis.request_config ON request_config.RIDGROUP = request.RIDGROUP
            AND currenttaxyear =2011
            AND weekno =33
            AND contractorsRef=outer_config.contractorsRef ############ERROR HERE###########
            GROUP BY contractorsRef
        )x
    )noworkers
    FROM bis.Request
    INNER JOIN bis.request_config ON request_config.RIDGROUP = request.RIDGROUP
    AND currenttaxyear =2011
    AND weekno =33
)T1 ON T1.contractorsRef = outer_config.contractorsRef
WHERE currenttaxyear =2011
AND weekno =33
AND outer_config.contractorsRef <>132
GROUP BY outer_config.contractorsRef
```

Table Def

-

```
CREATE TABLE request_config (
  RIDGROUP int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sessionstart text NOT NULL,
  EmployeeID int(11) NOT NULL,
  closedrequest tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  contractorsRef int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  timesheetDateSubmited text,
  requesttotal int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  imported int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  dateref text,
  onlinespreadsheet int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  marginamt double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  grossamt double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  feespaidbyclient int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  currenttaxyear int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  weekno int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  subdedamt double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  timesheetfrequency int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  onlinesubmission int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (RIDGROUP),
  KEY contractorsRef_2 (contractorsRef,currenttaxyear,weekno)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE request (
  RID int(11) NOT NULL,
  RIDGROUP int(11) NOT NULL,
  EmployeeID int(11) NOT NULL,
  date_requested text NOT NULL,
  hours double NOT NULL,
  rate double NOT NULL,
  agencydeduction double NOT NULL,
  otherpay double NOT NULL,
  totaltimesheet double NOT NULL,
  subcontractorRef text NOT NULL,
  candidatename text NOT NULL,
  candidatename_sys text NOT NULL,
  validated tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  requestclosed tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  paytypeID int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  retrieved int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY RID (RID),
  KEY RIDGROUP (RIDGROUP),
  KEY subcontractorRef (subcontractorRef(20))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE contractors (
  contractorsRef int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  contractorsName text,
  contractName text,
  TELEPHONE text,
  MOBILE text,
  FAX text,
  contractorsAddress1 text,
  contractorsAddress2 text,
  contractorsAddress3 text,
  contractorsAddress4 text,
  contractorsAddress5 text,
  contractorsAddresspostcode text,
  emailaddress text,
  websiteadd text,
  Contractsent int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  Contractreceived int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  officeno int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  clientID text,
  jobtype int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  weeknopaymentfilereceived int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  timetogenerateemail text,
  daytogenerateemail text,
  weeknoremindersent int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  weeknoremindersent_O2 int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  disabledreminder int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  active int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  createdbyEmployeeID int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  marginagreed double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  rebateagreed double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  marketing int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ARDENTORO2 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  www text,
  clientID2 text,
  attentionneeded int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNREFCOUNTER int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  feespaidbyclient int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  request_manual_entry int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  payupon int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  weektostartreminder text,
  reminder_duration int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  dayofweekpaymentexpected int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  Correspondence text,
  timesheetfrequency int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  atnc int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  nextts_expected int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (contractorsRef),
  KEY clientID (clientID(8))
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please provide your table definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It APPEARS that you are trying to get the following...
A list of each contractor.  From each contractor, how many distinct subcontractors they are working with.  From that, a total number of workers across all subcontractors for the contractor.  If this is correct, the query below might be closer to fit your needs.

The first "from" query just gets a query of the qualified conditions of contractor + subcontractor and counts grouped by contractor + sub.

From that result, get a query of the contractors, then COUNT of the subcontractors, and SUM the subcontractor workers count.

CREATE AN INDEX on your Request_Config table on (CurrentTaxYear, WeekNo, ContractorsRef ).  You want the index to represent the smallest granularity to find common groups.. In this case, either tax year / week (instead of week / tax year which would otherwise interlace all years for a given week, thus more records).  By indexing by year + week, you will only get those specific to the time period without interlace as just described.  Within THAT set, it will easily breeze by skipping over the one contractor ref you don't want.

Additionally, to help the group by (inner query), you may want another index on the Request table on both the RIDGROUP AND SubContractorRef(20) to help keep them pre-sorted in subresult set.

I've also adjusted the inner query after better review of your table structures to query based on the request config table FIRST and JOIN to the request table second.  The "WHERE" clause is directly applied to the config request table (optimize via index).

```
SELECT
      PreQuery.ContractorsRef,
      COUNT(*) as SubContractors,
      SUM( PreQuery.subCount  ) as SubContRequests
   from 
      ( SELECT 
              RCNF.contractorsRef,
              REQ.SubContractorRef,
              COUNT( * ) subcount
           FROM
              bis.request_config RCNF
                 JOIN bis.Request REQ
                    ON request.RIDGROUP = request_config.RIDGROUP
           WHERE
                    RCNF.currenttaxyear = 2011
                AND RCNF.weekno = 33
                AND RCNF.ContractorsRef <> 132
           GROUP BY
              RCNF.contractorsRef,
              REQ.SubContractorRef ) PreQuery
   group by
      PreQuery.ContractorsRef
```

**-- Another clarification of results --**

From your last comment... getting double-counted
Lets say you have the following records.

```
Request_Config
RIDGroup  ContractorsRef  
1         111     Even by this example, if a contractor ref can be 
2         222     duplicated as a different "RIDGroup" and would appear
3         333     two times.  This COULD / WOULD cause duplications when
4         111     joining to the Request table on just the ContractorsRef column


Request file
RID  RIDGroup  SubContractorRef
52   1         SubA
53   2         SubB
54   3         SubC
55   4         SubA
56   1         SubA  (second work/hours/pay request from same job?)
57   4         SubA  (second request for second job under same contractor)?
58   2         SubD
59   2         SubE
60   1         SubF

The INNER part of the query would return
ContractorsRef  SubContractorRef   Count
111             SubA               4  (as derived from 
                                          RIDGroup 1 having 2 entries and 
                                          RIDGroup 4 having 2 entries
111             SubF               1  (since only against RIDGroup #1, (not #4)
222             SubB               1
222             SubD               1
222             SubE               1
333             SubC               1
```

As you can see, the "SubA" still only appears ONCE for ContractorsRef 111, and shows 4 unique request entries for that sub...  So, the OUTER query where it only groups by the ContractorsRef would have

```
ContractorsRef  SubContractors  SubContRequests
111             2               5
222             2               2
333             1               1
```

(I changed the query column final names to properly reflect context of totals).

Comment: this works, but the query is taking longer than I would expect. Any other alternatives, thx?

Comment: @user984314, see revised answer and index comments.  This should significantly help the performance.

Comment: sorry dude, the result is not giving me unique subcontworkers though. 1 worker may have more than 1 record under the RIDGROUP. I wanted to come up with a quicker method for counting the records rather than the count(distinct) method. Any ideas? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: @user984314, so... are you saying a sub-contractor can work for more than one contractor... and you want to count that sub-contractor only ONCE?  Regardless of how many contractors they are working for?  If so, I would adjust the query to only associate the sub-contractor with the first contractor so they do not get double-counted... Is this more what you are looking for?

Comment: A sub contractor would work normally for 1 contractor. But there will definately times where 1 contractor will have more than 1 line of pay in his payment. So a client may sent over 1 x 200 and 1 x 100 for the same subcontractor. But what this report should show is a count of 1 instead of a count of 2 (which is what it's doing)

Comment: @user984314, updated answer and sample data simulation to help clarify.  Am I accurate?  Off? are you getting proper answer overall?

Comment: I'm really confused with the query. I have tried to run the ammended query, but keeps saying Unknown column 'RNCF.ContractorsRef' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user984314, sorry, my bad... fingers backwards... its the alias of the request config "RCNF", not "RNCF"  (nc backwards oops)